# how to validate two form of single page

Tags: javascript, html

I have Two Forms Here
**First is here**

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-signin" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/job/create" id="submitUpdateProfileForm" >
    <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="updateJob" autocomplete="false" autofocus="false">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtJobId">Job Id</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="txtJobId" name="txtJobId"   placeholder="Job ID" value="18" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtJobName">Job Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text"  id="txtJobName" name="txtJobName" placeholder="Job Name" value="" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtJobInstruction">Job Instruction</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="txtJobInstruction"  name="txtJobInstruction" placeholder="Job Instruction" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Create Quotation</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**And Second Is Here**

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" action="http://localhost:8080/files/upload/">
    <label for="users_file"> <strong><b> <font color="blue"> Please Select Image</font></b></strong>

        <input type="file" name="users_file" id="users_file" accept="images/*" />
    </label>

    <div id="filedrag" style="padding: 28px;border: 2px dashed #000000;"> <strong><b><font color="blue">Or Drop Files Here</font></b></strong></div>
</form>
```

Question Is how to validate select image in create quotation? My problem is " this code create quotation without knowing image is uploaded or not"

Comment: Please only use the snippets feature for _runnable_ code snippets. If you want to post code in your question, indent it by 4 spaces and it'll be syntax highlighted. Runnable snippets are a recent and, IMO, quite confusing addition to Stackoverflow

Comment: I am having hard time to understand your actual problem

Comment: Dear doniyor Sir, Please see below answer of msngupta. He understood my question clearly. I hope you will also get what my actual problem is. And please help me.

Comment: why do you use 2 forms? when you can just add them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to say that the "create quotation" form should not be submitted if no files are selected in the "select image" of second form, then you can add onsumit attribute to your first form in this way

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-signin" method="post" 
action="http://localhost:8080/job/create" id="submitUpdateProfileForm"
onsubmit="if (!document.getElementById('users_file').value.length>0){alert("Please upload a file!!");return false}else{return true}">
```

Here I am checking if the "users_file" input value is empty or not then submitting the form.
I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: You understood my question. But sir, it does not work.

Comment: @DeepakKarn There was a problem, I have modified the code see if this works

Comment: @DeepakKarn Let me know if you have more problems

Comment: Sir can i put an alert message here?? if so then how?

Comment: @DeepakKarn Made changes see if thats what you want

Comment: Sir in second form there is also an id called "filedrag". the above code that you written is work nicely for id="users_file". If i drag an image and create quotation it throws "pleas upload file". Please also validate for filedrag id.

Comment: Sir, Now i have to display all created job... but what i got there " created job are not displaying in ascending order". what to do sir? i'm using JSP,Jquery and Bootstrap.